# Rename on multiple files

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have a file named `HomePage.html` but I want to change it to `index.html`.
The problem is that if I want to change it I have to change it in all my files were I link towards this page to.

For example:

- File name: `Home-Page.html`
- Rename to: `index.html`

then I have 10 other files were I use the `Home-Page.html` in the navbar and I have to change this on every page.

I want to change 20 names this way and it will cost to much time if I have to change this on every page 1 by 1.

So how can I rename this in all files at once? I tried doing <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + R</kbd> but somehow that doesn't work... (maybe because I have `<a href="Home-Page.html">` things around it?)

Comment: Well .. yes -- invoke `Refactor | Rename` on file (in Project View panel) -- that dialog box has option for "Reference check" -- http://postimg.org/image/k0oulgggx/ -- try it (will work if IDE is able to recognize such references correctly, of course). Otherwise -- already mentioned `Find | Replace in Path (Ctrl+Shift+R)` and do it one by one (confirming each place to ensure that it's done correctly). If it happens that search does not find all places - consider doing `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE before that.

Comment: @LazyOne Ty this worked :D
The  ' File | Invalidate Caches...'   dud the job for me.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

(for the 30 characters I just write this with it..)

Fixed > By the comment from LazyOne

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP editor or IDE, use the "Search and Replace" function, it allows you to find and replace all the occurencies in your file. For example, replace "Home-Page" by "index". In sublime text, it starts with Ctrl+H

Comment: But then it only replaces it in that file and not in all the 20 files of my website were i want it changed on.